# How do I customize the fallback message on Lex V2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

This is a bit of a silly question but I wasn't able to find anything in the documentation or a spot to change it in the Amazon Lex console.

In Lex V1, there was a tab in the editor called ['Error Handling' where you could clearly change the messages for the clarification prompt and hang-up phrase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx8Uv.png).

I started working with Lex V2 only recently so I'm thinking it's a setting I've missed. How do I change the fallback intent message in Lex V2?

Comment: Select the fallback intent from your intents list - do you not have one?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I do have one. I've tried changing the values in the Fulfillment section of the FallbackIntent but even after waiting for the bot to build I did not see these changes reflected. Is there somewhere else in the FallbackIntent I should make edits?

Comment: Added an answer as it's very visual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fallback message is defined by the fallback intent specified for your bot, which is always required to exist for any bot.

Even if you are building your Lex bot from scratch, there will be an intent of type [`AMAZON.FallbackIntent`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/built-in-intent-fallback.html) created for you with the default name of `FallbackIntent`.

To find the fallback intent for your bot - regardless of if it has been renamed from the default value - perform a search for `AMAZON.FallbackIntent`.

This will yield an intent:

[image]

You can then specify the 'fallback message' by:

1. Ensuring the **Closing Response** is set to active
2. Specifying a value in the **Message** field

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. This is what I had done initially but the bot was still only returning "FallbackIntent Fulfilled" default response. I have created a new Lex and it seems to be working fine on that one. Do you have any idea what might've cause this issue? It was my understanding that the fallback intent should be the same across all Lex V2 Bots.

Comment: @Kera You're welcome. Are you sure you triggered a new build of the bot after making the change? A new build (version) would be needed before the changes take an effect.

Comment: Yes it was a new build.

Comment: @Kera Hm not sure really - maybe retry? I'd have to see all the intents to say but for this question, I hope your question has been answered 